# Any inherent bad effects to framesets?

Tags: html, frameset

I've got a client who wants to have their site shown through a frameset, something like:

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://www.real-site-address.com" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
```

The only argument I have against it is it will prevent anything from being bookmarked in the interior of the site. I think (not sure) also it breaks the back/forward buttons.

Are there other reasons why this would be unwanted?

Comment: It can mess up search engines, too, or reduce the effectiveness of searches for your site.  And some might take you to the inner frame when you do find a page, and then your page is less functional.

Comment: All the cool kids don't use it anymore.

Comment: @DanMan trust me, its not my idea .. just looking for arguments to make the to client. I don't think yours will go over well ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments mentioned in the question are strong enough against this kind of use for frames, but in addition to them, there’s the deception aspect. The idea of using frames this way is to make the address of the site look different from its real address. This very idea will often get revealed to users for various reasons, and they may feel deceived and may think that the site is amateurish (as it uses a cheap trick instead of proper hosting.

Screen reader software has special issues with frames and may address them by saying e.g. “the page has two frames” and by reading the titles or names of frames, letting the user select a frame. This won’t be a success especially if there are no suitable names to use, so that they can just be referred as “frame one” and “frame two”.

Answer (score 1):

Like you've mentioned: the loss of deep-links. It's impossible to share a link to a certain article for example, which in turn can hurt your link popularity and Page Rank rating.

So visitor statistics become more difficult or even partially impossible. In other words, try to convince them from an SEO angle. That always works wonders with CEOs.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I can think of is that you need to set a specific doctype. Just make sure you use it correctly: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/frameset

Comment: The use of a specific Frameset doctype affects validation only. Functionality does not depend on it. I don’t think this is a relevant argument against using frames.